# Нестандартный Balloon

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при выборе метки `balloon` не всплывал стандартно над меткой, а появлялся по нужным координатам (идеально - сбоку от карты) и с постоянным размером (независимо от содержимого)?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Можно создать собственный макет балуна или балуна панели. Вот пример собственного макета балуна: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan